# How can you keep a new view from covering the tab bar after a segue?

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a tab bar with 2 tabs. I ctrl-dragged from a button in the first view and released it on the second view and chose "show". The storyboard shows the tab bar on all the scenes, but when I test the button in the simulator, although it does segue to the second view, the second view doesn't show the tab bar.

How can you keep a new view from covering the tab bar after a segue?

Maybe I need to ctrl-drag somewhere else or do this programmatically?

Here is a screenshot of my story board.

[image: Storyboard screenshot]

When I segue to the "Read Article" view controller I would like to still see the tab bar and star icon at the bottom.

p.s. This may have been answered before with Objective-C, but I am looking for a Swift answer. Thanks.

Comment: `p.s. This may have been answered before with Objective-C, but I am looking for a Swift answer. Thanks.` If there isn't any runtime function in that code it should be pretty much the same. Nevertheless ... What do you actually want to achieve? Segue from a view controller (say VC1) inside a tabbar controller (VC0) to another view controller (VC2)? And the presented view controller (VC2) covers the tabbar? If so put VC1 inside a navigation controller. That should sove the problem. That's how it works with UITableViews.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but where would the navigation controller be located? I am adding a screen shot of my storyboard just in case that helps.

Comment: Allright, perfect. Just click on your `ReadArticleViewController` and choose `Editor` from the menu bar and then `Embed in` -> `Navigation Controller`.